# Why doesn't my page have session state when called as the default document of a directory?

Tags: asp.net, session

If I access my page like this...

```
/folder/default.aspx
```

...everything is fine.  If I access it like this...

```
/folder/
```

...the page has no session state.  Any ideas why?

This changed from IIS6 to IIS7, incidentally. In IIS6, it was fine.  The "Default Document" feature in IIS7 is enabled, set to "default.aspx".

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a mystery. One way you could try to discover the source of the problem would be to set breakpoints at several events in `Global.asax` and in the `.aspx` page. You'll have to write the code to create the event handler. Then, put some code in there to examine, for example, whether `Session` is null. Finally, step through and see if you can identify where the two URLs differ in behavior.

Events that I would start with include `Application_Start`, `Session_Start`, and especially `Application_BeginRequest` and `Application_AcquireRequestState`. There are other events interleaved in there that you might want to add once you've narrowed it down.